# null values for java.util.Date input/output in web service methods

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jaxb, jax-ws

I have a webservice created with jax-ws and netbeans 7's wizard (this is my first time) .
to use java.util.Date instead of XmlGregorianCalendar, I have modified the client's webservice with this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema"
                 xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
                               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
                                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:serializable/>
           <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xsd:dateTime"/>
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Date is now used instead of XmlGregorianCalendar and an Adapter1 is generated :

```
public class Adapter1
    extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>
{


    public Date unmarshal(String value) {
        return new Date(value);
    }

    public String marshal(Date value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.toString();
    }

}
```

When i add a system.out.println in the adapter i see that the Date is received/sent to the server  but if i use ws's methods i get always null on Date field/parameters .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlAdapter` that is generated is not going to perform the desired conversions.  The default `XmlAdapter` expects the following to work:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo(foo2.toString());
```

Which is not valid in this case:

```
Date date1 = new Date(date2.toString());
```

You will need to write some conversion code and reference it from an external bindings file:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="format.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='my-date']">
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType>
                    <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date"
                        parseMethod="org.example.DateFormatter.parseInt"
                        printMethod="org.example.DateFormatter.printInt" />
                </jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer .This kind of stuff is really complex for a newbie :p . Is there another way to use java.util.Date simply with jax-ws ? Thanks